# MPAndroidChart: BubbleEntry on same dataset and xAxis cannot be selected

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Currently using `v3.0.0-beta1` of [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) BubbleChart, in which I populated 5 sets of entries as follow.

```
BubbleDataSet set1 = new BubbleDataSet(group[0], "DS 1");
        set1.setColor(LifestyleActivity.CHART_RANGE_COLORS[0], 150);
        set1.setDrawValues(true);
        BubbleDataSet set2 = new BubbleDataSet(group[1], "DS 2");
        set2.setColor(LifestyleActivity.CHART_RANGE_COLORS[1], 150);
        set2.setDrawValues(true);
        BubbleDataSet set3 = new BubbleDataSet(group[2], "DS 3");
        set3.setColor(LifestyleActivity.CHART_RANGE_COLORS[2], 150);
        set3.setDrawValues(true);
        BubbleDataSet set4 = new BubbleDataSet(group[3], "DS 4");
        set4.setColor(LifestyleActivity.CHART_RANGE_COLORS[3], 150);
        set4.setDrawValues(true);
        BubbleDataSet set5 = new BubbleDataSet(group[4], "DS 5");
        set5.setColor(LifestyleActivity.CHART_RANGE_COLORS[4], 150);
        set5.setDrawValues(true);

        ArrayList<IBubbleDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
        dataSets.add(set1);
        dataSets.add(set2);
        dataSets.add(set3);
        dataSets.add(set4);
        dataSets.add(set5);
```

The data entry will consist of 2 information which is the `xaxis` (date) and `yaxis` (duration) value. Somehow, it I have 2 data that belongs to the same set in the same `xaxis` but a different `yaxis` (i.e. data1: `xaxis` is 12/1, `yaxis` is 5, data2: `xaxis` is 12/1, `yaxis` is 13), only one of it can be selected, despite zooming in/out.

An example is seen as illustrated, with each color indicating a different data set.

[image]

**But** both can be selected if it falls in a different data set (i.e. data1 in set1, data2 in set2). May I know if this is an intended behavior?

**Update**: The only one selectable value is the larger `yaxis` value of both two. So in the example's case, only data2 can be selected.

Comment: Same problem for scatter chart. Any answer yet?

Comment: A release was recently made `3.0.0` that fixed my issue. If i remember, it involved some fixes for scatter chart as well.

Comment: Nope, I used 3.0.0 already.